# OrientDb sql injection and escaping characters

Tags: .net, sql-injection, orientdb

How can I prevent sql injection when programming against OrientDb using the [OrientDB-NET.binary](https://github.com/orientechnologies/OrientDB-NET.binary)? Is there a way to escape special characters for Orient-SQL and work with string literals?

Example: I want to store this literal: `me' or 1 = 1 ),'//` and then be able to query it like

```
select from MyVertex where text = '...'
```

I'm having trouble doing this in OrientDb studio too.

I have found [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/orient-database/sytdxVTwk_w/zAR12xjZlhUJ) which is related to the Java driver, so I was wondering if there is something similar for .NET.

Answer (score 1):

## [You need to use parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).

These are queries that separate **data** from **syntax**, which is the root problem behind SQL injection.

In C#, using the OrientDB-NET binary, you want to do something like this (adapted from the [OrientDB-NET wiki](https://github.com/yojimbo87/OrientDB-NET.binary/wiki#query-and-command-methods):

```
using (ODatabase database = new ODatabase("yourDatabase"))
{
    PreparedQuery query = new PreparedQuery("SELECT FROM MyVertex WHERE text = ?");
    var selectedValue = database
        .Query(query)
        .Run([***Your Input Here***])
        .SingleOrDefault();

    var text = selectedValue.GetField<string>("text");
}
```

You can check out the [OrientDB-NET unit tests](https://github.com/orientechnologies/OrientDB-NET.binary/blob/441fb2fec10e50d659e26084010f3fe3c612d6ef/src/Orient/Orient.NUnit/Query/PreparedQueryTest.cs#L47) for PreparedQuery to see more examples of how you might do this.