# How do I prevent SQL injection with orientdb in php using PhpOrient?

Tags: php, sql-injection, orientdb

The [answer to the .Net question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32388683/385571) says to use parameterized queries, but what is the least bad way to handle parameters in PhpOrient while waiting for support for parameterized queriest?

There is support in OrientDB itself, but [currently not in the **official** PhpOrient](https://github.com/Ostico/PhpOrient/issues/17) driver.

Using [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) seems to be a strange solution to quoting parameters for an entirely different database, but what should I do if I want to allow data containing "junk" characters?

For the time being, I can validate and filter the data prior to construction of the queries, but it would be impractical for future projects.

Comment: "what is the proper way in php?" - **parameterized queries**, as in every other language.

Comment: I meant when it is not available, like in this case. I'll adjust the wording in the question to make it more clearer. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK PDO emulates parameterized queries on DBMS' and drivers not supporting them themselves - i'd look into a way to make it work with PDO (directly or indirectly via ODBC?)

Comment: This is not PDO and it is not MySQL.

Comment: I've been using PDO extensively since PHP 5.1 or so, so I know it quite well by now. OrientDB is new territory for me, and it has no PDO driver. I mentioned mysqli myself in a comment not directed towards anybody in particular.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann you *do* know if there is an orient driver for PDO?

Comment: I don't think there's a PDO drive for orient DB, urient db uses OrientDB-PHP drive.. check on gituhub https://github.com/AntonTerekhov/OrientDB-PHP. also check here  http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Programming-Language-Bindings.html